# Check if two unordered sequence are equal

Tags: python

I'm looking for an easy (and quick) way to determine if two unordered sequence contain the same elements:

For example:

```
GTTUIP and EGTP 
return [[0,1],[1,2],[2,2],[5,3]]
```

Comment: Does that sample output map the indexes of sequence 1 to the counts in sequence 2?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Brad , but i want to return the position of the equal element [[0,1],[1,2],[2,2],[5,3]]

Comment: The first line `GTTUIP and EGTP` does not appear to be correct Python. What are they? Input? Variables?

Comment: @usr2564301 it's a simple string of characters

Comment: Something like `str = "GTTUIP and EGTP"`? Please [edit] your question. Also, add what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following comprehensions will do:

```
s1, s2 = 'GTTUIP', 'EGTP'

i2 = {char: i for i, char in reversed(list(enumerate(s2)))}
# {'P': 3, 'G': 1, 'T': 2, 'E': 0}

[[i, i2[char]] for i, char in enumerate(s1) if char in i2]
# [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [5, 3]]
```

The former creates a lookup mapping from characters to their indexes in the second sequence. The `reversed` in there is to ensure we map to the index of each char's *first* occurrence. The latter builds the final structure by iterating the first sequence and looking up the indexes from the second.